# New conda environment is created without python

Tags: anaconda, virtualenv, virtual-environment, anaconda3

The [conda documentation](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html#creating-an-environment-with-commands) says that when you use

```
conda create --name myenv
```

The new environment

> uses the same version of Python that you are currently using because
>   you did not specify a version.

However, that's not the case for me. I have Windows 10 and Anaconda. I am into the "base" environment created by default.

If I run

```
conda create --name testenv
```

Then when I activate the environment

```
conda activate testenv
```

There is no Python. If I write

```
python
```

to the console the Microsoft Store is opened.

To have a Python interpreter I need to manually specify it

```
conda create --name testenv2 python=3.8
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

That specific note in the Conda documentation was a hold-over from before Conda v4.4 and has since been corrected (see [here](https://github.com/conda/conda/commit/039593cb40fcf388271331ac8f5fa242a3f0f278#diff-ebc307130628a2bad92f9173ca90dbd7) and [here](https://github.com/conda/conda/commit/33ed43adb0ab0bceb4d6544d222c5c965c349cc6#diff-ebc307130628a2bad92f9173ca90dbd7)).

#### Background

Previous to Conda v4.4, the **base** environment's `bin/` directory was always on the `PATH`, hence why not installing a Python interpreter in a new environment it would fall back to the **base** Python. Conda v4.4 introduced a new strategy for managing environment isolation via defining the primary interface to Conda as a set of shell functions and allowing the **base** `bin` directory only to be included on `PATH` when the **base** environment was active. This strategy provides cleaner isolation of environments, which means that only what is in the active environment will be available.

Hence, if you want Python in the environment, it must be explicitly installed.

Comment: Interesting, thanks for clean explanation. Just got a new computer and after recreating my work environment encountered this and was very weirded out lol. Obviously my previous conda hadn't been updated for a while!