# Command 'python' not found inside conda environment

Tags: anaconda, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am using Ubuntu 20.04 WSL on MS Windows 10. I installed anaconda from the homepage (https://repo.anaconda.com/archive/Anaconda3-2021.05-Linux-x86_64.sh) and tried to create a new environment as the following image.

[image]

As you can see, I just create a new environment and switch to that, and I found no Python command.

I did `echo $PATH` and got

`/home/my_username/anaconda3/envs/test/bin:/home/my_username/anaconda3/condabin:`

at the beginning of the PATH already.

How could I fix the problem? Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [New conda environment is created without python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62061533/new-conda-environment-is-created-without-python)

Answer (score 6):

I found the issue

When creating a new environment, we need to specify the version of Python

`conda create -n test python=3.8`

Comment: thanks, but why? I suppose the default python version will be used?